# Will keeping a GFCI tripped increase its lifespan?

Tags: electrical, gfci

[USA] I have recently replaced the receptacles in my house with tamper-resistant ones, including the GFCIs.

The GFCIs are the new auto-self-test type (Pass & Seymour 1597TR and 2097TR models). Some of these are in places where they will rarely be used.

I have read on here that GFCIs have a limited lifespan, and will eventually fail a self-test and need replacing. My question is: would keeping those rarely-used GFCIs in a “tripped” state keep them from aging, so that they last longer?

Note that the circuits would still be live, so the red LED would be lit. They would be reset only when it is necessary to use them.

Comment: Wouldn't that knock out the whole circuit?

Comment: So like not driving the car...

Answer (score 4):

[Is there any benefit to tripping a GFCI receptacle when it's not in use?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121231/is-there-any-benefit-to-tripping-a-gfci-receptacle-when-its-not-in-use)

[Does big current draw make GFCI outlets go bad?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/does-big-current-draw-make-gfci-outlets-go-bad)

I'd say you're over-optimizing. You only need 1 GFCI outlet on a circuit, and it'll last about 10 years. That's around $2/year. That's if GFCI outlets degrade from simply being attached to power; the second linked question indicates that heavy loads and similar usage causes the wear and tear.

Comment: In addition to this answer. Whether the device is in the tripped or non tripped position doesn't effect the condition of the device, but manually setting the device to tripped and non tripped will. Since it is a mechanical action and subject to wear. In short you are trying to use a the trip setting as a switch and it is not approved or rated as a switch.